# Face to face confrontation with an alien being

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Time frame: late 50's mid 60's and possibly from the UK.

A young boy or man witnesses a streak across the sky and it lands nearby in a misty-foggy moor. while investigating the perimeter of the craft, he finds himself in a face to face confrontation with an alien being while looking into a porthole on the craft.
This story scared the "you-know-what" out of me when I was an impressionable child.

Answer (score 7):

*The Man From Planet X* ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Planet_X), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043778/), [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/man_from_planet_x/), [Trailers from Hell](http://trailersfromhell.com/man-planet-x/#.U-GH8md0xhE)) is a 1951 Hollywood movie set in Scotland. It's got your alien spacecraft landing in a misty moor, all right. The [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7kEf-rW7ks) shows a young woman startled by an alien face looking back at her through a porthole. You can watch the whole movie [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x22a299_the-man-from-planet-x_shortfilms).