# Circa 1950-1960 sci-fi film: egg-shaped spaceship lands during a blizzard

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm trying to identify a science fiction movie that I *did* *not* see as a kid (parents caught me watching it and banned me from TV for three days). The period is late 1950's to mid-60's.

An egg-shaped spaceship has landed in a remote, very snow-laden location. People are aware that something's there but there's a blizzard outside. A woman curious about the ship goes exploring on her own. As the snow whips about her, she seeks out the ship and slowly moves along it. As she carefully peers into a "porthole" on the ship, a humanoid alien simultaneously and frighteningly does the same from the inside. She draws back... (parents enter the room and shut off TV).

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail, such as when you saw the film, when it was made, etc...

Comment: User 1411 has the answer. Mike, what was your parents' problem??

Comment: Ihor, as a creative and a parent I am on the liberal side although I would suggest its about knowing your own kids and timing. If they are easily led or sensitive then you would be more careful about content at a young age because it might lead them down a dark path they couldn't deal with... Roald Dahl at too young an age can be disturbing, the Witches for example, has kids being terrorised and eaten. Stephen King's IT is an entertaining novel with great characters and insights but gave me nightmares at 14 (my parents let me read most anything). Slept with the light on for a week.

Answer (score 7):

If it was fog rather than snow in the air, then I guess it was *The Man From Planet X* ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Planet_X), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043778/), [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/man_from_planet_x/), [Trailers from Hell](http://trailersfromhell.com/man-planet-x/#.U-GH8md0xhE)), which I proposed a while back as an answer to [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50270/face-to-face-confrontation-with-an-alien-being). Please check out the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7kEf-rW7ks). Or watch the whole movie [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x22a299_the-man-from-planet-x_shortfilms).

Comment: complete with porthole scene, judging from the IMDB forum http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043778/board/nest/13795408?ref_=tt_bd_2

Answer (score -2):

The Thing (1982) matches your desc with the snow and the humanoid thing. But timeline doesn't. Maybe there was an earlier rendition?